# Install pip after building Python from source

Tags: python, pip

I recently downloaded Python `3.10` from python.org and built it from the source, on Ubuntu `18.04`.  I had previously been on Python `3.8`.

According to https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/ "Usually, pip is automatically installed if you are using Python downloaded from python.org." But when I run `pip --version` or `pip3 --version` it shows as installed for Python `3.8`, not `3.10`.

I have these questions:

1. Is something wrong with my build that pip is not shown for Python `3.10`?  I've been using `3.10` for more than two weeks and haven't had any other problems.
2. According to the same page, I can upgrade pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Does the upgrade change it to Python `3.10`, or do I install it separately with either `sudo apt-get install python-pip` or `sudo apt-get install python3-pip python-dev`

I could just try these options, but I want to avoid problems.

Thanks.

Comment: After building from source, you can do the `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` thing, but change the first `python` to point to the executable in your build directory.

Comment: If I run "locate python3.10" I get a vast number of directories.  Which one has the executable?  Can I just alternatively execute "sudo apt-get install python3-pip python-dev"

Comment: `python --version` in the terminal will give you the python version. If the version is 3.10.x you can run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. The apt-get commands you suggest will most likely not give you the version you want, as 3.10 is still quite new.

Comment: It's python3 --version and it is Python3.10.0.  When I installed I did ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local --with-ensurepip=install so I don't know why pip is not installed.  Thanks for your comment -- I know the Ubuntu repository does not have 3.10.

Comment: I ran  pip3.10 --version and got pip 21.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10).  I didn't know there was a pip3.10.

Answer (score 1):

I built Python `3.10` from source with `./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local --with-ensurepip=install`, and `pip` was installed:

`pip3 --version`

WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with `-m pip` instead of running pip directly.

`pip 21.2.3` from `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip` (python `3.10`)

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01-1566673626429-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:/home/bin# ^C
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01-1566673626429-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:/home/bin# pip --version
bash: pip: command not found
```

Here's the issue.  Pip should be run as `python -m pip`.  See Brett Cannon's blog entry at https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip.

Some may already know this but I didn't and I hope this helps others in the future.